# Upgrade from Xtext 2.3.0 to 2.4.1: org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.validation.XtypeJavaValidator doesn't exist

Tags: eclipse, xtext

Where `org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.validation.XtypeJavaValidator` is supposed to be?

Xtext needs it in a generated file `Abstract*DslJavaValidator`. This type replaces `org.eclipse.xtext.validation.AbstractDeclarativeValidator` from Xtext 2.3.0 but I can't find this class anywhere in Xtext 2.4.1.

2.4 has `XbaseJavaValidator` but I'm not sure whether I should use this (the code being generated by Xtext and the access to this class being discouraged).

Are there instructions anywhere how to upgrade from 2.3 to 2.4?

By blindly messing the URL, I was able to generate a [list of bugs](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/buglist.cgi?f1=OP&list_id=7722745&f0=OP&status_whiteboard_type=allwordssubstr&f4=CP&query_format=advanced&j1=OR&f3=CP&status_whiteboard=v2.4&bug_status=RESOLVED&bug_status=VERIFIED&bug_status=CLOSED) with the title "Whiteboard: v2.4" but I'm not sure whether a) this is the actual list of bugs and b) how to get the list for 2.4.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The prefix of the class is generated from the base grammar. So if your grammar starts with

```
grammar ...
with org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.Xtype
```

the code generators will try to extend `XtypeJavaValidtor`. If you derive from Xbase, it will use `XbaseJavaValidtor` (i.e. name of grammar + `JavaValidtor`)

[This bug report contains a workaround](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=426478):

> Workaround: pass `inheritImplementation=false` in the workflow like this:
>
> ```
> fragment = validation.ValidatorFragment auto-inject {
>   inheritImplementation = false
> }
> ```
>
> Same is probably true for the `ImportNamespacesScopingFragment`, `ContentAssistFragment` and `QuickfixProviderFragment`